# DBI->connect throws ORA-12650: No common encryption error if silent.ora has SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_SERVER=(SHA256,SHA384,SHA512)

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi

I would appreciate your help in resolving this error in perl script. On database server (Oracle Database) sqlnet.ora has below settings

```
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_SERVER=(SHA256,SHA384,SHA512)
```

Due to which, we are getting error

Database connection not made:

```
ORA-12650: No common encryption or data integrity algorithm (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach)
```

If sqlnet.ora above line is changed as below

```
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_SERVER=(SHA1)
```

Database connection succeeds.

Unfortunately, the sqlnet.ora file can not be modified. I am wondering how to get Database connection and is there any specific attribute which can be passed to DBI->connect() method?

Comment: What is `sqlnet.crypto_checksum_types_client` (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/netrf/parameters-for-the-sqlnet-ora-file.html#GUID-8D134504-AFBA-489F-A663-E747A4660D46) set to on the client's sqlnet.ora?  Can you successfully connect from this particular client machine to this particular database from `SQL*Plus`?

Comment: For some reason the most comprehensive error code description had been left in ancient [9i reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/tnsus.htm#1656), but: "**TNS-12650** No common encryption or data integrity algorithm
**Cause**: The client and server have no algorithm in common for either encryption or data integrity or both.

**Action**: Choose sets of algorithms that overlap. In other words, add one of the client's algorithm choices to the server's list or vice versa."

Comment: SQL*Plus as well throws same error ORA-12650: No common encryption or data integrity algorithm. Is there someway we can override algorithm used by sqlnet.ora of client while calling DBI->connect()?  One workaround is to modify client machine sqlnet.ora.

Comment: @user419534, why don't use your own sqlnet.ora file in client side matching the encryption supported in the server ? You can create a sqlnet.ora and tnsnnames.ora file whenever you want and export or set the TNS_ADMIN variable to that folder

Comment: ...and no, there is no way to override those parameters in the code. Set the correct matching values in the client's sqlnet.ora.